# Locked out from wordpress due to missing password

Tags: wordpress

I have tried to reset my user credentials in wordpress following the [link](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/forgot-your-password-how-to-recover-a-lost-password-in-wordpress/) however without successful result
How can I recover my wordpress account if I don’t remember the email, user or password?

Comment: Do you have access to hosting?

Comment: Are you talking about self hosted WordPress or the SaaS WordPress.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't remind your log-in account or the email address or username you’ve entered isn’t recognized, and you can’t use Two-Step Authentication to reset your password, you can access your account using the [Account Recovery Form](https://wordpress.com/wp-login.php?action=recovery). On this form, you **need to verify that you are the owner** of the blog in question:

**Transaction ID:** A transaction ID is a unique alphanumeric code generated for your payment. If you purchased an upgrade on the blog in question — via PayPal, credit card, or another method — you can retrieve a transaction ID by logging in to your PayPal account or locating a past WordPress.com receipt sent to your email address.

**Activation URL:** When you created your WordPress.com account, we sent an activation link to your email address that you were required to click. If the email you received included a confirmation button instead of a link, you can copy the activation URL by right-clicking on the button and selecting “Copy Link Address” (this text may be vary slightly depending on your browser).

At the bottom of the form, you can add any other details that may help. Then, click **Recover My Account**. The Wordpress Support team will contact you with a response or a request for additional information. Once they have proof verifying you are the blog owner, you will be able to reset your password and regain access to your WordPress account.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you’re speaking of WordPress.com or the open source software.

If you’re on WordPress.com, you can find their recovery process here:

https://wordpress.com/support/account-recovery/

If you’re using the open source software and the password reset link you request from your site’s login screen doesn’t arrive/work, you can also reset the password directly in the database by accessing PHPMyAdmin from your hosting control panel.

https://wordpress.org/support/article/resetting-your-password/

You’ll need to contact your hosting provider’s support for access to PHPMyAdmin, though I recommend that as a first step anyway - many hosting providers who provide dedicated WordPress hosting can reset your admin credentials for you if needed.